# legend not working in afreechart in tablet android

Tags: android, charts, legend

I am using Afreechart to create charts for my android app. In emulator legend is visible but in android tablet legend is not showing up. Previously it was working properly but when i add some other activities to my app,its not working. am using afreechart-0.0.4.jar.my minSdkversion 3 and target is 15.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for my question..

The thing that pointed me in the right direction was the fact that the graphs would behave perfectly on the emulator, independently from what version of Android the emulator was running. That made me think that maybe the hardware acceleration (which if I am not mistaken was introduced with HoneyComb) had something to do with this. A little more googling showed me that other graphics libraries had similar issues on ICS and JellyBean, so I tried switching off the hardware acceleration for the chart view:

chartView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Now the graphs and the legends show up just as expected on any device. Hope it helps someone....